# Select model association property as model property in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Whenever I do a `findAll` or `findOne` on a model and it involves nested association. All the property of the association also get nested. Like below :

```
ProductQCStatus.findAll({
            include:[
                {
                    model:Product,
                    include:{
                        model:ProductImage
                    },
                    attributes:["product_name","product_description","category"]
                }
            ],
        })
```

It will be below result

```
[{
   //fields from ProductQCStatus table 
    Product:{
         product_name: value
         product_description: value,
         ... 
         ProductImage:{
             images:[]
         }
  },
{
   //fields from ProductQCStatus table 
    Product:{
         product_name: value
         product_description: value,
         ... 
         ProductImage:{
             images:[]
         }
  }
......
]
```

I want the result not be nested but just one object with all the attributes defined inside nested associations.

I have already tried `map()`, also using other functions through which I can iterate and get the desired fields. But in that case, I  have to traverse whole objects. I don't want that.I went through documentation, and I couldn't find anything there.
I wonder if there is any native method in sequelize itself to achieve this.